# How to insert column in powerpoint using VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

The questions is bit tricky one, I have googled and got a link http://joelblogs.co.uk/2010/08/13/automatically-create-summary-slides-in-powerpoint-2010/  with VBA code which helps me to insert summary of the titles of all the other slides of one presentation in single parent slide.
The code is working fine, however when the number of slides with titles is more than 30 or 50 then the Table of content parent slide cannot hold the entire title names as the names will be hidden and go beyond the slide presentation.
Hence, I like to confirm are there any VBA code to distribute the contents of the summary names in to three columns through VBA in the table of contents slide ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link where you have an example you need to add that code at the and of your macro:

```
With summary.Shapes(2).TextFrame2
    .Column.Number = 3
End With
```

which set 3 columns in your summary text frame.
Remember, that you could need to set font size, too, to keep your text within text box.

**Additional information:** What I see is that font size changes (decrease) as long as you put more text into summary Shape (`Shapes(2)` in my example). You could then trace the font size to check if you should increase number of columns. Here is an example:

```
With summary.Shapes(2).TextFrame2
    If .TextRange.Font.Size < 20 Then
        'additionally check here if max approved column numbers is not exceeded.
        .Column.Number = .Column.Number + 1
    End If
End With
```

And here is my full basic test code (which could be run for any new empty presentation):

```
Sub test_loop()
    Dim summary As Slide
    Set summary = ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(1, ppLayoutText)

    Dim enterText as string
Do
    enterText = InputBox("Additional text to insert into Shape:")

With summary.Shapes(2).TextFrame2
    .TextRange.Text = .TextRange.Text & Chr(10) & enterText
    If .TextRange.Font.Size < 20 Then
        .Column.Number = .Column.Number + 1
    End If
End With

Loop While enterText <> ""
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi kazJaw,                                                          It works perfectly thanks for the piece of excellent code, however I would like to know if there is any code which can add columns in the slide based on number of increase in title names (that is more number of slides), i have a doubt this can fulfilled using tables in slide, please give your thought on this ?

Comment: Hi kazJaw the code which you wrote is excellent, however i would like to know instead we feeding the font size is more or less in number and increase the columns, is there any possibility where the font size is more than 8,20,22,32 under these parameters there must be an array to loop the font size in textframe2 and increase the columns, whether the code can be tweaked for to acheive this ?

Comment: I would rather make some tests and extend `If` statement with additional `ElseIf` conditions. Array and loop could be helpful but you have rather 'static' situation.

Comment: Hi kazjaw thanks for the update,However i would like to know what this below code does                                                                    With summary.Shapes(2).TextFrame2
    .TextRange.Text = .TextRange.Text & Chr(10) & enterText
    If .TextRange.Font.Size < 20 Then
    .Column.Number = .Column.Number + 1                                                                     I tried the above code in my code the title font size in the new Table of contents Slide is 18, however it will create only 2 columns where the title names will go beyond the slide margin.

Comment: That part adds new text to summary **TextShape** which is automatically font resized if text is too big. Then it checks current **font size**. If current font size is lower than 20 it **adds new column** to that **TextShape**. The best option is to run that code with F8 and check what is going on. Than you will understand.

Comment: But it helped me to add only 2 columsn and all other 15 slides went beyond below the slide margin and no further columns were added :-(, what might be the issue ?

Comment: go to PP Application >> RightClick on that TextBox >> find something like 'Shape format' at very bottom >> find something line 'Text Field' on the left >> check something like 'Wrap text in shape'...

Comment: The wrap text in shape did not help me to update all the table names in one slide, still thetitle names are beyond the slide margin, did the wrapping of text in slide helped you ? or is there any way to automate the same to reduce the space within slide based on the size fo the text ? please give your thought on this

Comment: What do you mean by `reduce the space`?? my advise, do some manual tests. Set text box parameter in that way that is within the slide and each time you put manualy (!) more and more text the shape keep the size but changes the font size (reduce it). You must figure that setting out on yourself. That macro will do the rest for you. I suggest once again- start new complete empty presentation and run my macro within this presentation to check how it works.

Comment: Hi Kazjaw all these days i tested the code and it works fine, however is there any modification for the code we can do after the number of title names increases to 55 or 60 in shape then insert new slide and continue with the title names numbering after 60th slide (i.e. 61 62 63 .....etc) ?

Comment: it is feasible, but I think you could start new question for that... and one suggestion, if you like any of the answers you have received you could either approve it, or up-vote it, or do both. that's what people like here :)